# Why do I encounter this error?(Error : not all code paths return a value)

Tags: c#

```
public static int Salary()
    {
        
        try  
        {
            int salaryDays;
            Console.Write("Enter salaryDays: ");
            salaryDays = Console.Read();

            int workDays;
            Console.Write("Enter your workDays: ");
            workDays = Console.Read();
            var salary = salaryDays * workDays;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This salary code is incorrect.");

        }

     }
```

I didn't get any results by searching on Google. It didn't solve the problem with error management either. Can you guide me?

Comment: Because there is not a single `return` statement in this method that is supposed to return an `int`

Comment: It's fixed, thank you. Now I realized that I needed a dust return

Comment: Also, `Console.Read();` returns the next "character". For example `'1'` and not `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't have a `return` statement, but in the declaration it states that it has to return an `int`.

Notice that if you have a control flow in your code that determines multiple exit points from the method, in every exit point you have to return something or throw an exception.
That's why the error message says *not all code paths...*

So, your code can be fixed this way:

```
public static int Salary()
{
    
    try  
    {
        int salaryDays;
        Console.Write("Enter salaryDays: ");
        salaryDays = Console.Read();

        int workDays;
        Console.Write("Enter your workDays: ");
        workDays = Console.Read();
        var salary = salaryDays * workDays;
        return salary;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Console.WriteLine("This salary code is incorrect.");
        throw new Exception("This salary code is incorrect.");
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return both from `try` and `catch` blocks. Fix your method as follows:

```
public static int Salary()
{
    try
    {
        int salaryDays;
        Console.Write("Enter salaryDays: ");
        salaryDays = Console.Read();

        int workDays;
        Console.Write("Enter your workDays: ");
        workDays = Console.Read();
        var salary = salaryDays * workDays;
        return salary; // Add this line
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This salary code is incorrect.");
        return -1; // And this line
    }
}
```